# Sweet Alert Dialog ic_launcer is packaged in version 1.3 and causing compiling issues

Tags: android

When including Sweet Alert dialog in the project, I encountered an issue which caused comilation issues, due to a duplicated ic_launcher dialog which was packaged in the library

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher) from AndroidManifest.xml:7:9-43
    is also present at [com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-45 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-22:19 to override.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Solution was pretty simple, the solution is to add these two lines into the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" //manifest element 
tools:replace="android:icon"  //application element
```